# CRM 2011 Administrator is missing read privilege error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a user in CRM 2011 having System Administrator security role [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b923b.png), when I use that user in my Web Service to retrieve `Account` entity this error comes up

```
Principal user (Id=927fbba4-d61a-e311-992b-000c295c9030, type=8) is missing 
prvReadAccount privilege (Id=886b280c-6396-4d56-a0a3-2c1b0a50ceb0)
```

Comment: I am unable to add image to post. I dont know why
 but here is the url you can check from

   http://i.stack.imgur.com/b923b.png

Comment: are you 100% sure that you are using that user for your webservice?

Comment: yes i figured it out....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue:

Below is the work-around if some is having issue:

I We had assigned the user Administrator role:

```
Looking at different user fields in CRM I cam across:
Clien Access License (CAL) Information:
```

It was having values:

```
Access Mode : Administrative
License Type: Full
```

So I changed the Access Mode to :

```
 Read-Write     // Yahooooooooooooooo everything is working on the fly :)
```

Thanks for your time people.

Answer (score 0):

The System Administrator role has *all* privileges on *all* records and this cannot be limited in any way.

I have two hypothesis(es?)

1. Your Web Service isn't actually operating under credentials of a user having the System Administrator role. This is the most probable explanation, you have to make sure your connection gets passed the correct username/password(/domain unless IFD).

Since you have an ID to check against, you can double check who that user is with a simple OData query:

```
[crm url]/XrmServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/SystemUserSet(guid'927fbba4-d61a-e311-992b-000c295c9030')
```

1. Your CRM setup is messed up (highly unlikely unless you've been fiddling with the database, in that case odd errors and misbehaviors become a quite real possibility)